# Warning in WDired when renaming files to change capitalisation

Tags: dired

I often use the command C-x C-q in dired (bound to dired-toggle-read-only) to rename files.

When I use this to change only capitalisation (eg, Foo.bar to foo.bar) then I use C-c C-c to apply the changes (wdired-finish-edit), I get a warning saying

> File /../../foo.bar already exists; rename to it anyway? (y or n)

I get that I couldn't create two files with the same name if the difference is just the capitalisation, but I believe this warning is not necessary if I am just renaming a file. I think WDired could be made aware of the fact that it is just renaming a file and not creating a new one with the same name. Is there a way to fix this so I don't get the warning if I am just renaming a file with dired-toggle-read-only?

(I am aware that I can use R on dired to rename a file, but I often change names in bulk, even using the rectangular selection to remove blocks of characters from many file names at once).

Comment: Are you, perhaps, using OS X?

Comment: @Dan Yes, I am... So I gather it has to do with that. Any way to work around it somehow?

Comment: I believe OS X file names are case insensitive, which is probably why dired is warning you that the file already exists.

Comment: @Dan OK, I get that, but I am just renaming the file, I am not creating a new one. I don't mind the warning if I am trying to create a new file, but I don't want the warning when I am renaming the file, the same way I don't get one if I use the command R in dired to rename a file.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. This seems like a reasonable thing for Emacs to handle by default, in cases where it can ascertain that the already-existing "new" file is actually the same file as the "old" one.

Comment: For the layman or hobbyists (such as myself), `rename-file` is a C-source code function that is beyond the reach of mere mortals -- *probably* the reason why a bug report has been suggested, rather than an `elisp` modification/tweak.

Comment: @lawlist It's probably quite easy for you and most people to find the C line in question. Fixing it is another issue: HFS+ can be case-sensitive or case-insensitive. I'd probably leave the behavior as-is.